# ActiveMQ stops 'talking'

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-karaf

We have an OSGi (Karaf 4.0.5) server that uses Camel 2.15.4 & ActiveMQ 5.12.0 for remote calls to services within the server.

After the server has been up for several weeks ActiveMQ sometimes appears to stop taking any new connections from outside the server. Remote clients attempt to make connections, but they eventually just time out.

The problem is we don't even know where to start looking for what the problem might be. There are no specific errors in the server log that seem to pertain to ActiveMQ or Camel.

We can log in to the Karaf console and do a `activemq:bstat`, but we have hundreds of queues for all the services, so it's like a needle in a haystack, and we don't know what the needle looks like.

Can someone please tell us what things we should look out for?

ActiveMQ XML config:

```xml
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
        useJmx="true" brokerName="${broker-name}" dataDirectory="${data}" start="false">

    <destinationPolicy>
      <policyMap>
        <policyEntries>            
          <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
            <pendingSubscriberPolicy>
              <vmCursor/>
            </pendingSubscriberPolicy>
          </policyEntry>
          <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
          </policyEntry>
        </policyEntries>
      </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>


    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
    </managementContext>

    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${data}/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>

    <plugins>
        <timeStampingBrokerPlugin futureOnly="true"/>
    </plugins>

    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="tcp" uri="tcp://localhost:4210"/>
    </transportConnectors>
</broker>
```

Comment: ActiveMQ 5.12.0 was released in 2015 if I recall so I might start with a broker upgrade.  Otherwise debug logs and JVM heap dumps would probably be your friend in debugging this.

Comment: Yes, we do have it on our todo list to upgrade this server (it's still using Java 8), but there are a lot of dependencies to work through there. So there is no useful info in the 'activemq:bstat' or dstat that might give us a clue?

Comment: Also, can you suggest a logging category to put to DEBUG?

Comment: You should also checkout the size of the log files in case they're hogging out all the space on the server or hit some limit assigned to the broker. This can lead to some weird behavior hand hanging connections.

Comment: Yeah, we do get a lot of the kahadb 'db-???.log' files, which I believe are the 'Dead Letter Queue', but there is usually plenty of disk space when ActiveMQ stops talking.